# JSF get original URL

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I provide my user an URL: `http://foo/show.jsf?id=1`

However when the user is not logged in I throw an `SecurityException` and in my `web.xml` I define the errorPage für this exception to be `login.jsf`.

Now the user sees the `login.jsf` but the URL still looks like this: `http://foo/show.jsf?id=1`

After login I want to redirect my user to `show.jsf` (or whatever original url was specified). But in order to do this, I would need to somehow get the original request URL. Is it possible to get this URL somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Where you throw your exception (using a filter to authenticate?) you have to somehow save the original requested URL via `HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()` and redirect afterwards.

Comment: well yes, a filter throws the exception. Can I redirect within a filter?